# Trying to replace some javascript on a website with a message

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, message, edit

I'm trying to replace some javascript on a website, below is the code i would like to change:

```
function() {ActionButtonClick(ShipmentEntryAction.ProcessAndPrint);}}
```

I would like to check if a textbox is filled or else give the message Empty!.

This is my code so far but i'm a beginner in javascript, maybe someone can help me?

```
function() {ActionButtonClick var tracking=document.getElementById("Tracking1").value; if (tracking==""){alert("empty!");}else{(ShipmentEntryAction.ProcessAndPrint);}}
```

Thanks!